# Procedure for any type of array in Fortran

Tags: templates, fortran, overriding

**Basis:** I want to write a procedure which make some operation for any input array type: `integer, real(4), real(8)`, etc. The only idea i read on StackOverflow is to imitate C++ templates, using generic procedures for overriding and preprocessor for including duplicating code.

But searching for API of popular I/O software, i found this in manual:

```
function nf90_put_var(ncid, varid, values, start, count, stride, map)
    integer, intent(in) :: ncid, varid
    any valid type, scalar or array of any rank, intent(in) :: values
    ...
```

And it really works normally for every array type of **every** rank, passed to `values`.

**Question:** They can't predict any rank, so they cant make explicit templates for every case. How i can build the same friendly interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same situation as with the MPI procedures. The key is (at least in Fortran 2008 and older) to use implicit interface to the routine. In that case no argument checking takes place and you can pass whatever you want. You have the implicit interface if the procedure is external.This is the same situation as with the MPI procedures. The key is (at least in Fortran 2008 and older) to use implicit interface to the routine. In that case no argument checking takes place and you can pass whatever you want. You have the implicit interface if the procedure is external.

Example:

```
     subroutine store(A,count,sizeof)
         use iso_fortran_env, only: int8
         integer, intent(in) :: count, sizeof
         integer(int8) :: A(count*sizeof)
         integer :: u

         !here you can treat A just as an array of count*sizeof bytes
       open(newunit=u,file=out.bin,access=stream)
        write(u)  A
        close(u)

     end subroutine

     program p
       real :: A(5,6)
       call store(A, size(A), storage_size(A(1,1))/8)

     end program
```

When you need the explicit interface, you could (untested) do something like (not supported by many compilers, beyond Fortran 2008):

```
    subroutine typebound(self, A, count, sizeof)
      class(my_class) :: self
      TYPE(*),DIMENSION(..) :: A
      integer, intent(in) :: count, sizeof

      !subroutine
      call store(A, count, sizeof)
```

or use the directives which a few compilers support:

```
    !GCC$ attributes no_arg_check::A
    !DEC$ attributes no_arg_check::A
```

this disables the check of the arguments.

Comment: *at least in Fortran 2008 and older* -- don't tell me you have a more modern compiler already !

Comment: No, but some compilers support selected features from the following TS (further interoperability with C).

Comment: Ahhh !  Thanks, that was a useful update, I'll see what my compiler makes of it.

Comment: Could you please extend your example and add program calling this sub, and sub, for example, just writing input array. I cant figure out how to code this correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Two more questons: 1) Does it mean, that i can pass this byte array directly to MPI subroutine, for example? 2) How can i use this trick with class procedures? (idea is to override one of the class methods)

Comment: 1) yes, the MPI buffers can be anything 2) you are out of luck, you need explicit interface for that, you can use the `generic` specifier and write all versions yourself. It will not be completely generic.

Comment: It depends if you really want any type, even those you don't know beforehand,  and any rank or just some combinations.

Comment: 1D, 2D, 3D ranks and integers, real4, real8 types. So i have choice: make my classes just modules (and somehow make subroutines to be external) or use classes and generic specifier?

Comment: For these limited combinations you can write all versions yourself and use `generic`. Note that this is completely different from your original request to explain `nf90_put_var`

Comment: Just want to simplify code as possible. Implicit interfaces firstly seemed perfect choice, but i'll miss classes in this case. So generic is the only choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the last part of Vladimir's answer: The `mpi_f08` module defines most routines with the following unportable part, which seems to suit most compilers (but most likely, not all):

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: sendbuf, recvbuf
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: sendbuf, recvbuf
!$PRAGMA IGNORE_TKR sendbuf, recvbuf
!DIR$ IGNORE_TKR sendbuf, recvbuf
!IBM* IGNORE_TKR sendbuf, recvbuf
```

(Adjust the variable names according to your needs.)