# Fortran interface allowing rank-1 arrays and scalars

Tags: arrays, function, interface, fortran, prototype

*Background: GCC 10 removed support for calling subroutines with different typed arguments. My aim is to write an interface that respects both `integer, dimension(:)` and `integer`*.

(Which means I can't use other options such as embedding the scalar in an array. I have to change the interface)

According to [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C.html#Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C):

> It is possible to provide standard-conforming code which allows different types of arguments by using an explicit interface and `TYPE(*)`.

[and](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C.html#Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C):

> Note, however, that `TYPE(*)` only accepts scalar arguments, unless the `DIMENSION` is explicitly specified. As `DIMENSION(*)` only supports array (including array elements) but no scalars, it is not a full replacement for `C_LOC`. On the other hand, **assumed-type assumed-rank dummy arguments (`TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..)`) allow for both scalars and arrays**, but require special code on the callee side to handle the array descriptor.

In the interface below I have `type(*), dimension(:) :: data`. How can I change it according to the text I've emphasized above?

```
module z
    interface
        subroutine a(data)
            type(*), dimension(:) :: data
        end subroutine a
    end interface
contains
    subroutine b(data)
        integer :: data
        call a(data)
    end subroutine
    subroutine c(data)
        integer, dimension(:) :: data
        call a(data)
    end subroutine
end module
```

[Godbolt playground](https://godbolt.org/z/_iFYML)

Comment: [GCC 10 changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html): "Mismatches between actual and dummy argument lists in a single file are now rejected with an error" which created [chaos for package manager maintainers](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/54364#issuecomment-626316365). Thanks, the duplicate does answer my question.

Comment: There is no duplicate marked here (it was for less than a minute, long before your comment). Be aware that the change followed the practice of many established compilers, notable the Intel Fortran compiler, and the programs were *not* standard conforming. And most importantly, such calls were **never supported**. Therefore gfortran did never remove any such support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of GCC 10 removing anything (what is your source for that?) but exactly for the reasons you mention, GCC also introduced the directive

```
!GCC$ attributes no_arg_check::A
```

(see [Procedure for any type of array in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032511/procedure-for-any-type-of-array-in-fortran) )

which was already used in other compilers that enables the procedure to be called with any arguments, scalars or arrays of any rank, mainly for routines that accept buffers of any type, particularly in MPI libraries.

The new `DIMENSION(..)` is not really suited for use within Fortran, it requires special code that understands the standard Fortran array descriptor and it is mainly expected that it will be written in C. However, according to the very page you linked https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C.html#Further-Interoperability-of-Fortran-with-C gfortran does *not* yet support the standard array descriptor.

Comment: Yes, that relevant code is written in C++ (F2C) so I'll use `dimension(..)`. Thanks.

Comment: @MCCCS In that case be aware that gfortran does not use the standard array descriptor and the ISO_Fortran_binding.h header file is not available. The array descriptor is subject to change to the standard one at any time. If you just want to get a pointer to some buffer, just use the directive.

Comment: @Vladmir, you seem to be misinformed.  gfortran has provided ISO_Fortran_binding.h since 9.1 was released (first entered the source tree on 2019-01-12).

Comment: @evets I seem to quote the linked documentation. I certainly cannot be held responsible if it is not up to date.

Comment: Send a bug report to the gfortran devlopers.  Those guys are not infallible.